# How to get the exact number integer when the decimals are many in python?

Tags: python, integer

When there are too many decimal values, the return is never the integer present in the value, but a higher one, how should I proceed so that this doesn't happen?

---

Adition using `decimal`:

```
from decimal import *
a = 2.999999999999999999999999999999999999
b = Decimal(str(a)).quantize(Decimal('1.'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)
print(b)
```

Result `3` instead of the correct value that would be `2`

---

```
a = 2.999999999999999999999999999999999999
b = str(a)[:str(a).find('.')]
print(b)
```

Result `3` instead of the correct value that would be `2`

```
a = 2.999999999999999999999999999999999999
b= int(a)
print(b)
```

Result `3` instead of the correct value that would be `2`

```
import math
a = 2.99999999999999999999999999
print(math.modf(a))
```

Result `3` instead of the correct value that would be `2`

How should I proceed to always retrieve the correct integer?

Comment: Python can't represent `2.99999999999999999999999999` as a float, it gets stored as `3.0` instead. Consider using the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module if you require more precision than a regular float provides.

Comment: @SuperStormer well, 64bit binary floating point numbers cannot, not really *python* per se

Comment: Hit @SuperStormer i try use ```Decimal(a).quantize(Decimal('1.'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)``` but the result is ```3```, as the number can change in relation to the amount of decimals, I don't have a fixed value to define the precision, could you help me with this obstacle? Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: You need to create the decimal from a string, otherwise you're just making 3.0 into a Decimal.

Comment: @SuperStormer I did the test using ```Decimal('2.999999999999999999999999999999999999')``` as a string and it worked perfectly, but what about when the value comes from a number, I tried ```str(a)``` and the return was ```3```. As the number will come from a result of calculations, it will come from numbers, I have no way to generate it directly from a string made manually.

Comment: then convert those calculations to use Decimals.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not understanding how I can make this calculation result become a string because when I try to generate the string the value is already 3. I'll try to test more calmly, anyway, thank you very much!